# Batch - Extract every word on a line to a markdown link

Tags: batch-file, markdown, extract

This is code from a call above it. I extract line 5 from a file with this code which leaves it in %%c. I then want to take each word in that line (there can be from 1 to nth words) and create a markdown link like

```
[word](word.html)
```

and append those to a txt file. This is what I have so far. If I have 10 words do I really have to add all the tokens in the command like %%d, %%e, etc.? Can I use something like tokens=1-*. * meaning the last token in the line? Using tokens=* uses the whole line of words as one token I believe.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "lineNr=5"
set /a lineNr-=1
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%c in (`more +!lineNr! "%~1"`) DO (
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims= " %%d in ("%%c") do (
echo [%%d]^(tags/%%d.html^) [%%e]^(tags/%%e.html^) ^<br^> >> index.txt
)
goto :eof
)
```

Comment: no you don't need to assign each metavariable.. Take this as an example:

Comment: `set "str=this is a 6 word string"`

Comment: `for %%i in (%str%) do echo [%%i](tags/%%i.html)`

Comment: So in your case. The first for loop gets the string, you can then just run the exact same but remove linefeeds..

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can do that. Note I just used some parts as an example as I do not have time to format escape characters now, but you'll get the idea `:)`

```
@echo off
set "lineNr=5"
set /a lineNr-=1
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%c in (`more +%lineNr% "%~1"`) DO set "line=%%c"
for %%i in (%line%) do echo| set /p =[%%i](tags/%%i.html)>>index.txt
```

Comment: I only get the last line of a file using this which makes sense. The more command will start at line 5 here and make the var "line" equal to every line in the file as more executes. When more is finished, "line" contains only the last line in the file and that is what "set" writes to index.txt

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got it working by doing this -

```
set "lineNr=5"
set /a lineNr-=1
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%c in (`more +%lineNr% "overview.md"`) DO (
set "line=%%c"
goto :next
)
:next
for %%i in (%line%) do echo| set /p =[%%i](tags/%%i.html) >> index.txt
```

Have to break out of the loop line listing after the first line wanted(line 5).